# What would the tsql be for this type of database schema?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, schema

[image]

I [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419931/help-designing-a-database-schema-for-a-pizza-store), and someone suggested this type of schema. I'm not familiar with how super/subtypes work. Can you show me a TSQL example of how I would create this database?

Another problem I'm having trouble wrapping my head around, is given an order, and a collection of items in that order, how would I know if an item is a Pizza, Beverage or Side dish?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables:

### ITEM_SUPER_TYPE

- ITEM_SUPER_TYPE_ID (pk, IDENTITY)
- DESCRIPTION

### ITEM_SUB_TYPE

- ITEM_SUB_TYPE_ID (pk, IDENTITY)
- ITEM_SUPER_TYPE_ID (fk to ITEM_SUPER_TYPE.ITEM_SUPER_TYPE_ID)
- DESCRIPTION

### ITEM

- ITEM_ID
- ITEM_SUB_TYPE_ID (fk to ITEM_SUB_TYPE.ITEM_SUB_TYPE_ID)

This way, the super type can be inferred from the subtype.

Comment: But a single row in the supertype might be related to a row in every subtype table. The answer and comments to this SO question explain how to avoid that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969133/database-design-problem

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use Super Keys to constrain subtypes

- Item would have a TypeID column (lookup to a new table ItemType)
- New ItemType 1=Pizza, 2=Sides, 3=Beverage etc
- There is a new unique constraint on Item with current PK column(s) + TypeID
- Each table Pizza, Beverage, Sides has a typeID column with a CHECK constraint to restrict entries in the table to one of Pizza, Sides, Beverage. So 1 for Pizza etc.
- The FK from Pizza, Beverage, Sides to Item is the same as the new unique constraint above

This answers your second question too